# The class 'DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject' was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Help please.

I get this exception submiting my form.
I use Zend Framework 2 and DoctrineORMModule.

I generated my entities by means of next commands

```
php doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping annotation module/Globuserp/src/ --namespace="Globuserp\Entity\\" --from-database

php doctrine-module orm:generate-entities module/Globuserp/src/ --generate-annotations=true
```

Stack trace:

```
    #0 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php(113): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::classNotFoundInNamespaces('DoctrineModule\\...', Array)
    #1 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(117): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass('DoctrineModule\\...', Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata))
    #2 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(318): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), NULL, false, Array)
    #3 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(211): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('DoctrineModule\\...')
    #4 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(265): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('DoctrineModule\\...')
    #5 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/Stdlib/Hydrator/DoctrineObject.php(119): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata('DoctrineModule\\...')
    #6 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/Stdlib/Hydrator/DoctrineObject.php(102): DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject->prepare(NULL)
    #7 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Fieldset.php(591): DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject->hydrate(Array, NULL)
    #8 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Element/Collection.php(274): Zend\Form\Fieldset->bindValues(Array)
    #9 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Fieldset.php(584): Zend\Form\Element\Collection->bindValues(Array)
    #10 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Fieldset.php(584): Zend\Form\Fieldset->bindValues(Array)
    #11 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Form.php(364): Zend\Form\Fieldset->bindValues(Array)
    #12 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Form.php(513): Zend\Form\Form->bindValues()
    #13 /var/www/globus-erp.local/module/Globuserp/src/Globuserp/Controller/IndexController.php(85): Zend\Form\Form->isValid()
    #14 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): Globuserp\Controller\IndexController->addNewProjectAction()
    #15 /var/www/globus-erp.local/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/BaseController.php(20): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #16 /var/www/globus-erp.local/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/BaseAdminController.php(17): Application\Controller\BaseController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #17 [internal function]: Application\Controller\BaseAdminController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #18 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #19 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #20 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #21 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
    #22 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #23 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #24 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #25 /var/www/globus-erp.local/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(316): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #26 /var/www/globus-erp.local/public/index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
    #27 {main}
```

IndexController

```
    namespace Globuserp\Controller;

    use Application\Controller\BaseAdminController as BaseController;
    use Globuserp\Form\AddNewEmployeeForm;
    use Globuserp\Form\AddNewProjectForm;
    use Globuserp\Entity\Projects;
    use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
    use Zend\Http\Response;

    use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;

    class IndexController extends BaseController
    {
       //...

         public function addNewProjectAction()
         {
            $em = $this->getEntityManager();
            $form = new AddNewProjectForm($em, 'addNewProject');
            $request = $this->getRequest();

            if($request->isPost())
            {
                $data = $request->getPost();
                $newProject = new Projects();
                $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em, '\Projects'));
                $form->bind($newProject);
                $form->setData($data);

                if($form->isValid())
                {
                    var_dump($newProject);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                $result = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
                $result->setTerminal(true);
                return $result;
            }


       }
    }
```

Basecontroller

```
    namespace Application\Controller;

    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

    class BaseController extends AbstractActionController
    {
    protected $entityManager;

    public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e){
        $this->setEntityManager($this->getServiceLocator()->get("\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"));
        return parent::onDispatch($e);
    }

    public function setEntityManager(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entity)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entity;
    }

    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }
    }
```

AddNewProjectForm

```
    namespace Globuserp\Form;

    use Application\Form\BaseForm;
    use Globuserp\Form\EmployeeFieldset;
    use Globuserp\Form\ProjectFieldset;
    use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;

    class AddNewProjectForm extends BaseForm
    {


    public function createElements()
    {
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

        $projectFieldset = new ProjectFieldset('project', $this->objectManager,         new DoctrineHydrator($this->objectManager, '\Globuserp\Entity\Projects'));



        $this->add($projectFieldset);




        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Сохранить',
                'id' => 'btn_submit',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
            )
        ));

       }
    }
```

BaseForm

```
    namespace Application\Form;

    use Zend\Form\Form;
    use DoctrineModule\Persistence\ObjectManagerAwareInterface;
    use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

    abstract class BaseForm extends Form implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface
    {
        protected $objectManager;

        public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager)
        {
            $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        }

        public function getObjectManager()
        {
            return $this->objectManager;
        }

        public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager, $name=null)
        {
            parent::__construct($name);
            $this->setObjectManager($objectManager);
            $this->createElements();
        }

        abstract public function createElements();

   }
```

EmployeeFieldset

```
    namespace Globuserp\Form;

    use Application\Form\BaseFieldset;
    use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
    use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;

    class EmployeeFieldset extends BaseFieldset
    {

        public function __construct($name, ObjectManager $objectManager)
        {

            parent::__construct($name, $objectManager);
            $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($this->objectManager, '\Log'));

        }

        public function createElements()
        {
            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'employee',
                'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Имя сотрудника',
                    'object_manager' => $this->objectManager,
                    'target_class' => 'Globuserp\Entity\Staff',
                    'property' => 'fullname',
                    'label_generator' => function($targetEntity)
                    {
                        return $targetEntity->getFullname();
                    }
                ),
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'required' => 'required',

                )
        ));


        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'startTime',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'min' => 3,
                'max' => 100,
                'label' => 'Время работы на проекте'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control input-small',
                'required' => 'required'
            )
        ));



        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'endTime',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'min' => 3,
                'max' => 100,
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control input-small input-small-last',
                'required' => 'required'
                )
          ));
        }
    }
```

ProjectFieldset

```
    namespace Globuserp\Form;

    use Application\Form\BaseFieldset;
    use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
    use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
    use Globuserp\Entity\Projects;

    class ProjectFieldset extends BaseFieldset
    {

        public function __construct($name, ObjectManager $objectManager, DoctrineHydrator $hydrator)
        {

            parent::__construct($name, $objectManager);
            $this->setHydrator($hydrator);
            $project = new Projects();
            $this->setObject($project);
        }

        public function createElements()
        {

            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'title',
                'type' => 'Text',
                'options' => array(
                    'min' => 3,
                   'max' => 100,
                    'label' => 'Наименование'
                ),
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'required' => 'required'
                )
            ));

            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'color',
                'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Цвет',
                    'object_manager' => $this->objectManager,
                    'target_class' => 'Globuserp\Entity\ProjectsColors',
                    'label_generator' => function($targetEntity)
                    {
                        return $targetEntity->getTitle() . "#". $targetEntity->getValue() ."";
                    }
                ),
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control color',
                    'required' => 'required',

                )
            ));

            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'description',
                'type' => 'Textarea',
                'options' => array(
                    'min' => 3,
                    'max' => 100,
                    'label' => 'Описание'
                ),
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'required' => 'required'
                )
            ));

            $this->add(array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
                'name' => 'employee',
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Добавить сотрудника',
                    'should_create_template' => true,
                    'target_element' => new EmployeeFieldset('employee', $this->objectManager)
                )
            ));

        }
    }
```

BaseFieldset

```
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

abstract class BaseFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param mixed $objectManager
     */
    public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getObjectManager()
    {
        return $this->objectManager;
    }

    public function __construct($name, ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->setObjectManager($objectManager);
        $this->createElements();
    }

    abstract public function createElements();

}
```

Projects.php

```
 
namespace Globuserp\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Projects
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="projects", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="projects_ibfk_1", columns={"color"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Projects
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \Globuserp\Entity\ProjectsColors
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Globuserp\Entity\ProjectsColors")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="color", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $color;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Projects
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Projects
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set color
     *
     * @param \Globuserp\Entity\ProjectsColors $color
     * @return Projects
     */
    public function setColor(\Globuserp\Entity\ProjectsColors $color = null)
    {
        $this->color = $color;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get color
     *
     * @return \Globuserp\Entity\ProjectsColors 
     */
    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }
}
```

Log.php

```
namespace Globuserp\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Log
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="log", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_project", columns={"id_project"}), @ORM\Index(name="id_staff", columns={"id_staff"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Log
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $startTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $endTime;

    /**
     * @var \Globuserp\Entity\Projects
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Globuserp\Entity\Projects")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_project", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $idProject;

    /**
     * @var \Globuserp\Entity\Staff
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Globuserp\Entity\Staff")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_staff", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $idStaff;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set startTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startTime
     * @return Log
     */
    public function setStartTime($startTime)
    {
        $this->startTime = $startTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getStartTime()
    {
        return $this->startTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set endTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $endTime
     * @return Log
     */
    public function setEndTime($endTime)
    {
        $this->endTime = $endTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get endTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEndTime()
    {
        return $this->endTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set idProject
     *
     * @param \Globuserp\Entity\Projects $idProject
     * @return Log
     */
    public function setIdProject(\Globuserp\Entity\Projects $idProject = null)
    {
        $this->idProject = $idProject;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idProject
     *
     * @return \Globuserp\Entity\Projects 
     */
    public function getIdProject()
    {
        return $this->idProject;
    }

    /**
     * Set idStaff
     *
     * @param \Globuserp\Entity\Staff $idStaff
     * @return Log
     */
    public function setIdStaff(\Globuserp\Entity\Staff $idStaff = null)
    {
        $this->idStaff = $idStaff;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idStaff
     *
     * @return \Globuserp\Entity\Staff 
     */
    public function getIdStaff()
    {
        return $this->idStaff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You try to hydrate `NULL`. So somehow you hydrate while you don't have an entity Check your stack trace for:

`DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject->hydrate(Array, NULL)`

So you need to look at that.
Maybe you forget **[to initialize your Collections](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html#initialize-collections-in-the-constructor)** or something?
Or you otherwise try to hydrate a `NULL` object.

Answer (score 0):

I forget execute setObject method in EmployeeFildset constructor.
The correct version should be as follows

```
public function __construct($name, ObjectManager $objectManager)
{

    parent::__construct($name, $objectManager);
    $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($this->objectManager, '\Log'));
    $logEntry = new Log();
    $this->setObject($logEntry);

}
```